# How to include refreshing JWT token in makeReconnectingWS solid-primitives

Tags: websocket, solid-js

I am using makeReconnectingWS from solid-primitives.
My WebSocket server expects a JWT token to authenticate the connection, so I include it in the url.
Problem is, this token expires after some time and is refreshed. But the url parameter of makeReconnectingWS is not reactive, so I am wondering how to include the new token when the socket is reconnecting ...?